# Huge framerate drop when drawing surface on screen

Tags: c++, sdl

I just started to make another small game in SDL, i made my 2 players - represented by the top half of a circle. So far, i draw a background, and the two players on top.

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) return 1;
    if (!(screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH,SDL_HWSURFACE| SDL_DOUBLEBUF)))
    {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Surface* surface2 = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32,
                                   rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

    SDL_FillRect(surface2, 0, SDL_MapRGBA(surface2->format,0,0xAA,0,0xFF));

        //in the while loop
        SDL_BlitSurface(surface2,0,screen,0);
```

When i move the player, it moves 10px per movement. I have implemented smooth movement, with timers, so that is not the case. The intersting part is, that when i choose to leave the surface2 black - without a fillrect at the start, then everything works smooth.
I now fill the screen surface with a color, and it also runs smoothely. So what might be the problem?

Comment: Try using http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_MapRGB instead of SDL_MapRGBA.

Are you sure your "SDL_FillRect" is not called in the loop ?

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to have format mismatch?

Comment: @halflings when i comment out that single rect, the problem disappears. changing to MapRGB does not help.

Comment: @ddriver both surfaces have 32 bits of depth, both of them are stored on the v-card. They are also the same size.

Comment: I remember there was a significant performance drop in the case where format conversion is needed. This might be the pixel format, the alpha format (premultiplied or not) and so on.

Comment: @ddriver they are both hw surfaces, so they are in the same pixel format. Is there a possibility to turn of aplpha blending completely?